# c++ and .sys files

Tags: c++, operating-system

I have homework i cant figure out. I know c++ but i am not familiar with how it binds into OS. If someone cant direct me to a tutorial that does anything near to this, or anything whatsoever that could help me i would appreciate it:

You need to build a program (named parser) in Bash or in C that does the following:

1. Takes as argument one executable file name.
2. Runs the file with `-h` Argument and read the possible options.
3. Open an option file (named as the same name of the executable to run with `.sys` extension) and get the option values from the file
4. Reruns the executable by giving the correct arguments.

Example:

- Suppose you want to run a program named `PIZZA`.

  ```
  ./parser PIZZA
  ```
- The program parser should run    `./PIZZA -h`    To get the help of the PIZZA program
- You receive as help the following:

  > PIZZA   Options Where options can be 
  >     -L(number)   Specify the number of
  >   large pizza   -M(number) Specify the
  >   number of medium pizza    -S(number)
  >   Specify the number of small pizza
  >   Example: PIZZA –L0 –M5 –S3
- Read the configuration file `PIZZA.sys`

  > ```
  > L=5
  > M=0
  > S=1
  > ```
- Run PIZZA with the options

  > ```
  > ./PIZZA –L5 –M0 –S1
  > ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following Bash tutorial http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial

I don't really see any need to write C code to achieve what you're trying to do.

The odd thing about this assignment is the use of a `-h` option to show the help text. Most Linux commands use `--help` instead (or man pages).